# How to scroll with arrow keys in a Kirigami ScrollablePage?

Tags: qt, qml

The Qt QML based mobile/desktop convergent UI framework [Kirigami](https://kde.org/products/kirigami/) provides a QML type [ScrollablePage](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/classorg_1_1kde_1_1kirigami_1_1ScrollablePage.html) to support scrolling through content. Placing any visual QML item into it automatically makes it scrollable if it's larger than the ScrollablePage itself:

> ScrollablePage is a Page that holds scrollable content, such as ListViews.
>
> Scrolling and scrolling indicators will be automatically managed.
>
> ```
> Kirigami.ScrollablePage {
>     id: root
>     //The rectangle will automatically be scrollable
>     Rectangle {
>         width: root.width
>         height: 99999
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ([source](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/classorg_1_1kde_1_1kirigami_1_1ScrollablePage.html#details))

This provides scrollbars and allows scrolling with the mouse wheel, two-finger-scrolling with the touchpad and flicking ("click and throw") scrolling as we're used to from touchscreen devices.

However, it does not allow scrolling with any keyboard keys (Arrow Up / Down, Page Up / Down). How can I make that possible? The [usual approach](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#attaching-scrollbar-to-a-flickable) of doing `Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()` does not work because the ScrollablePage's scrollbar is not accessible as part of its public API.

Answer (score 0):

### Instructions

Use a `Flickable` to wrap the content items you put into your `ScrollablePage`. Then evaluate key press events in the `Flickable` and in response execute `flick()` to scroll the view. Example (combining examples [from the Kirigami manual](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/classorg_1_1kde_1_1kirigami_1_1ScrollablePage.html#details) and [from the Qt manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#attaching-scrollbar-to-a-flickable)):

```
Kirigami.ScrollablePage {
    id: root

    Flickable {
        focus: true
        topMargin: 20; leftMargin: 20; bottomMargin: 20; rightMargin: 20

        Keys.onUpPressed:   flick(0,  800)
        Keys.onDownPressed: flick(0, -800)

        Rectangle {
            width: root.width
            height: 5000
        }
    }
}
```

### Details and Explanation

While you can't access the scrollbar, you can access what the scrollbar uses to move the view: a `Flickable` instance. You just have to wrap it around the page's content. If you don't, ScrollablePage internally uses ScrollView to [wrap your page's content in a Flickable](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/-/blob/147c40a5bf06f6d7ec437da81b26f6807cc8962f/src/controls/templates/private/ScrollView.qml#L40) anyway, but then you don't have a reference on it to execute `flick()`.

Executing `flick()` does the same as when the user flicks the element, so the scrollbar position etc. will be updated alright.

If it still does not work, then (1) maybe you give too small pixel/second values to [`Flickable::flick()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#flick-method) for scrolling to be visible or (2) maybe the initial [`Flickable::flickDeceleration`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#flickDeceleration-prop) values on your platform are messed up. These values are platform specific, so it can require some experimentation. On some platforms, setting them to zero during a `flick()` [will help](https://forum.qt.io/post/277184), while under Linux this is exactly the value preventing any scroll movement.

It is not necessary to enable [`ScrollablePage::keyboardNavigationEnabled`](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/classorg_1_1kde_1_1kirigami_1_1ScrollablePage.html#a12a86be977a1e10bdbe53a3d21270ba1) for the above solution to work, since that is only for moving the `currentItem` of suitable content with the arrow keys (see below), and not for scrolling in general. It will even prevent ordinary scrolling in case your page content is an item view (`ListView`, `GridView` etc.).

### Alternative solution for item views

If the content of your ScrollablePage is an item view (any QML object that has a `currentItem` property, such as `ListView` or `GridView`), then instead of wrapping that content in a `Flickable` just enable [`ScrollablePage::keyboardNavigationEnabled`](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/classorg_1_1kde_1_1kirigami_1_1ScrollablePage.html#a12a86be977a1e10bdbe53a3d21270ba1). It will allow you to move the `currentItem` with the Arrow Up and Arrow Down keys. That's what one usually wants for these views, even though it's not scrolling but rather keyboard navigation.